# How to scale/crop Youtube video in Android?

Tags: android, youtube-api, surfaceview, android-videoview, android-youtube-api

I'm using `YouTubePlayerView` of YouTube Android Player API. I just want to get the center view of the video like this:

[image]

Is there anyway to do that ?

Comment: So its not a scale but crop?

Comment: @Abbas Yes, I just want display the center view in the phone. It there anyway to crop this

Answer (score 0):

You can't crop a video while playing via the android `youtube-player-api`. You also can't hide any part of the video by overlaying another view on top of it or the player will throw [UNAUTHORIZED_OVERLAY Error](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason).

So if you ever try to hide the player by putting a `View` or two on either side then you can't. However there is one way to cover the `YouTubePlayerView`: `Dialog` and `DialogFragment`, you can put up either a `Dialog` or `DialogFragment` add some views and cover the video partially to give that special crop effect. From these two IMO `DialogFragment` is the better choice (you may feel differently).

Another way to crop the video would require complete change of player on your part. You'd have to switch to a `WebView` based player i.e. play your videos in a literal browser (there are lots of `WebView`-based players available on github). A `WebView` unlike `YoutubePlayerView` or `YoutubePlayerFragment` will not throw the nasty `UNAUTHORIZED_OVERLAY` Error. However you will see ads and the default player controls while the video is being loaded. I guess you might be able to hide the `WebView` or overlay another view on top of it while the video is loading and use the YouTube Data API to put a thumbnail on top, but I've never tried it.